# bundelPath without app name

Tags: xcode, cocoa-bindings

i need to get the path of the app (bundlePath  or bundleURL) without the app name

```
NSUrl *strUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundleURL];

NSString *str = [[NSBundel mainBundel]bundlePath];
```

how do i go about

Answer (score 3):

Both `NSURL` and `NSString` have methods to remove the last path component, so this should give what you are looking for:

```
NSURL *strUrl = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];

NSString *str = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```